# Macro / VBA fails to run without entering the VBA password

Tags: vba, passwords

I have a VBA macro with password protection (preventing unauthorised access to the macro) that runs as expected. User clicks button, macro runs. The content is more or less:

```
   Sub sample()
   ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="xyz"
   ...VBA code....etc
   ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="xyz", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True,        cenarios:=True
  End Sub
```

Now I have added a Function so the code looks like:

```
Function 
......etc
End Function

Sub sample()
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="xyz"
...VBA code....etc
code referencing the function
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="xyz", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True,  Scenarios:=True
End sub
```

If the workbook is opened and the VBA window is opened and the VBA password entered, the macro runs fine every time. The worksheet password access works fine.

However if I reopen the workbook as a user, who will not have access to the VBA code, the macro will not run until the VBA password has been entered. I am guessing that the reason is the function is 'outside' of the sub-routine but putting inside the sub-routine won't allow the macro to run. I do not want the user to access the VBA code, they only need to run the macro.

Looking forward to an easy answer!

Comment: There is something I don't get: You speak of a password to access VBA code (we can use one to lock all code) but here it seems (`ActiveSheet.Protect`) that you are just protecting the sheet with a password. So: do you mean you protect the sheet with a password and the vba code is in the sheet and not a separate module? Or am I totaly wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get well the point but two points:

1./ If you want to protect all your code with a password (If not already done):

In your vba editor:

> Tools > VBAProject Properties > Protection

2./ Then the fact is that `sample()` locks the Sheet for the user (who doesn't have the password) AND the code when you use:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="xyz", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True,  Scenarios:=True
```

If you want to have your code access the Sheet with no restriction but you wnat the Sheet to be protected by a password (protected from users) you can use:

```
UserInterFaceOnly:=True
```

like that:

```
ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="xyz", DrawingObjects:=True, _
    Contents:=True,  Scenarios:=True, UserInterFaceOnly:=True
```

So your code can access everything, but users will still need a password to edit the sheet.

I don't know if it is what you need, I hope so. If not, you mat think of reformulation your question a little

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to achieve with protecting/unprotecting your code and all that. Personally, I think you're looking at it the wrong way.

In my company, we have an extensive set of VBA add-ins (.xla and .xlam) that are password-protected (and even digitally signed for security and to prevent tampering). A lot of them reference each other in an attempt to structure them as "clipboard add-in", "general utils add-in", etc. in order to keep their size and functionality separate. In this example, the general utils add-in keeps a reference to the clipboard add-in in order to call "Public" functions from it (you can't call Private routines across modules or from the workbook).

Only we know the passwords to the add-ins, but the client can call "Public" functions and subs without any issues, the same way we call such functions and subs between our add-ins. We also have a huge set of "Private" routines inside the add-in modules, but that's ok since they're used internally only.

We also supply a set of workbooks that make use of those add-ins by having references to a number of the add-ins, which are also protected. However, all the functionality is available to the users and we even have an unprotected VBA add-in that hosts our VBA API -- a thin layer of Public routines that map into the protected code.

Clients do not need to know what's going on inside the add-ins. The only thing they need to know is the publicly available API add-in that we supply and they can use it to automate all sorts of things.

I know this is probably not the answer you were looking for. I'm just offering a, hopefully useful, alternative approach that you may want to consider.